# Java / Android Client-Server application. Questions about security: Digital certificates and CAs

Tags: java, android, security, x509, digital-certificate

I'm currently developing an application for Android thay will allow users to back up their data on a server, which I am also developing in Java.  I've pretty much completed the development of the features such as file transfer, registering and logging in and so on (mysql database keeping records of users and passwords) and so on. I've come to a halt in my development when trying to implement security features.  I want to use asymmetric cryptography for authentication and symmetric cryptography for encrypting communication between client and server. So here is the deal:

The communication between client and server will be doing using AES. This relies on a Preshared key between both parties. This Preshared key will be generated on the client side each time a session is initiated and will be sent to the server, encrypted using the servers public key. That way, only the server that posses the private key will be able to decrypt the Preshared key and read the communication. Where I am a bit confused is the sharing of the servers public key. Now I know the best way to do this is to use a digital certificate containing the servers public key. I also know this certificate should come from a trusted CA.

My question is, how do I go about getting a digital certificate for my server? Will my android application request for this certificate from the server or the CA? My initial thought is that it has to receive this certificate from a CA, as if it receives it from the server, it may be fraudulent. What is the process and the correct way of going about this?  Anywhere I read, it just talks about https connection from client to Web server. I am writing a server in java that will communicate over sockets with my android application. How do I go about creating, receiving and verifying certificates in relation to trusted CAs?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to re-invent TLS? TLS doesn't require that you buy certificates (you can use your own) and even lets you use pre-shared keys directly.

Comment: For educational purposes, I'd prefer not to use TLS. Wouldn't using a certificate made by you not be secure as it is not verified by a trusted CA?

Comment: For educational purposes it is reasonable to study TLS specification then - it would be more secure, that's for sure. As for certificates - the "trusted CA" is trusted by particular software that validates certificates. You can add your own server certificate to the list of trusted certificates. I.e. this is a matter of trust, not of CAs per se.